# add unique constraints in column that related existing auto-inc primary key / partition key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb, alter-table, unique-key

**summary**
in mysql,
I want add uniqueness to existing column, without drop table, but it spits error because of existing auto-increment / primary key / partition key.

**describe**
I have table like below. and already have some rows.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_tx_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(id) 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY KEY(id)
```

and I changed my mind, I want add constraint to column event_tx_id also unique.

**I tried**

1. when I try alter table like this (add unique),

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MONDIFY COLUMN event_tx_id varchar(64) UNIQUE;
```

it spits error that

```
Error Code: 1503. A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function  0.078 sec
```

2. so I tried partition by key, first, then

```
ALTER TABLE my_table PARTITION BY KEY(id, event_tx_id);
```

then spits

```
ALTER TABLE my_table PARTITION BY KEY(id, event_tx_id); Error Code: 1503. A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

3. tries above needs changing primary key. so when I try to change primary key (drop -> add, because there isn't modify method)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY   Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

it complains about YOU CANNOT CHANGE(DROP) PRIMARY KEY THAT HAS AUTO-INCREMENT..

is there any way to handle this .. ?
thanx.

Answer (score 2):

- Uniqueness constraints do not work on Partitioned tables, except where the partition key is part of the constraint.
- Partitioning rarely provides any performance benefit, or any other benefit.  What were you hoping to achieve?